# Return object when aggregating grouped fields in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-database

Assuming the following example model:

```
# models.py
class event(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    attendance = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get the attendance number for the latest date of each event location and type combination, using Django ORM. According to the [Django Aggregation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#values), we can achieve something close to this, using `values` preceding the `annotation`.

> ... the original results are grouped according to the unique combinations of the fields specified in the values() clause. An annotation is then provided for each unique group; the annotation is computed over all members of the group.

So using the example model, we can write:

```
event.objects.values('location', 'type').annotate(latest_date=Max('date'))
```

which does indeed group events by location and type, but **does not return the `attendance` field**, which is the desired behavior.

Another approach I tried was to use distinct i.e.:

```
event.objects.distinct('location', 'type').annotate(latest_date=Max('date'))
```

but I get an error

```
NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.
```

I found some answers which rely on database specific features of Django, but I would like to find a solution which is agnostic to the underlying relational database.

Comment: Well you can never be 100% agnostic: all features django offers in the ORM are to some extend related to common features a *relational* database offers, but there are other types of databases like *graphical* and cascading (MongoDB for example).

Comment: You are right, I should clarify that I meant relational. I will update my question.

Comment: what do you mean with `value` field, the annotation?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `attendance`. I will update once again!

Comment: So if I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you are trying to figure out how many people will be in attendance for an event, like a concert?

Comment: Well the model is just an example, but the objective is to get the attendance of the chronologically last event for each event location and type combination.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think this one might actually work for you. It is based upon an assumption, which I think is correct.

When you create your model object, they should all be unique. It seems highly unlikely that that you would have two `event`s on the same `date`, in the same `location` of the same `type`. So with that assumption, let's begin: (as a formatting note, class `Names` tend to start with capital letters to differentiate between `classes` and `variables` or `instances`.)

```
# First you get your desired events with your criteria.
results = Event.objects.values('location', 'type').annotate(latest_date=Max('date'))

# Make an empty 'list' to store the values you want.
results_list = []

# Then iterate through your 'results' looking up objects
# you want and populating the list.
for r in results:
    result = Event.objects.get(location=r['location'], type=r['type'], date=r['latest_date'])
    results_list.append(result)

# Now you have a list of objects that you can do whatever you want with.
```

You might have to look up the exact output of the `Max(Date)`, but this should get you on the right path.

Comment: I don't think this works. The annotate returns a dict which does not contain the `attendance` key.

Comment: Did you try adding attendance to the values?

Comment: You cant do that because that would create unique location/type/attendance combinations before annotating. I just need the unique location/type combinations.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. Unfortunately I have already tried that and it doesn't work. The second `values` following the `annotate` "breaks" the grouping of unique combinations provided by the first `values`. As a result, you get the attendance for every event object.

Comment: Ok. This is my last shot. Updated answer.

Comment: As stated in my original question, I am looking for a solution using Django ORM directly rather than looping through. Thank you for your effort though.

Comment: Sorry. Guess I didn’t understand your question.